# jQuery rotate and slide from right

Tags: jquery, rotation, position

I have this script: http://jsfiddle.net/AVsyD/

HTML:

```
<div id="giraffe_right">
    <img src="http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/292/d/d/stock_png_giraffe_head_by_earthymoon-d4dadcn.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 150px;
    right: -15px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I want that image to be by it's default state out ouf the screen and rotated 90% to right, and every 1 minute slide to left until its state from fiddle (rotated until that state too, so rotated back from right) and stay like this for 5 seconds, then go back to right and the 90% right rotation. I don't know how to do this! All I know is that I need to use the window width, as you seen in the fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AVsyD/1/ try this

Comment: It is ok, but I want to add a transition to it and when it rotates back to 90 degrees, I want it to move I want it to move to the right untill it goes out of the screen.

Comment: check this out --> http://jsfiddle.net/AVsyD/3/